# With the death of CSUR, has there been any new Unicode proposal for con-scripts?

Tags: unicode, writing-systems

The [CSUR](http://www.evertype.com/standards/csur/) (ConScript Unicode Registry) is — or, rather, with its last update in 2008, was — a project "to coordinate the assignment of blocks out of the Unicode Private Use Area (E000-F8FF and 000F0000-0010FFFF) to constructed/artificial scripts, including scripts for constructed/artificial languages." As its authors do not seem to be involved with it anymore and the page suffering neglect, I can assume the project has stalled or died. Has anyone come up with a similar project since?

Comment: Is the CSUR really dead, i.e., are there conscripters that tried to submit an encoding proposal recently and failed to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There exists the [UCSUR (Under-ConScript Unicode Registry)](http://www.kreativekorp.com/ucsur/) which was created as a sort of temporary holding place for proposals to avoid conflicts until the CSUR is once again active.

Comment: The page doesn't seem to have any contact information - how can you submit a new script?

Comment: The [about](http://www.kreativekorp.com/aboutkk/) page has an email, I can only assume this is where to contact for proposals.